# Store the output from a test in new variable, vector, etc

Tags: r

I am using `adf.test` on my data to check for stationarity. I wish to store the pvalue of the test in a new variable so that I can use it for further processes.

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
x <- adf.test(Timeseries_1)$pvalue
```

But this is not working! Any help?

In continuation to the above, I am trying to extract the value of MAPE from the accuracy check but am getting the following error.

```
> etsfit <- ets(TS_1)
> accuracy(etsfit)

> if(accuracy(etsfit)$MAPE<10){
+ fcast <- forecast(etsfit)
+ plot(fcast)}else{print("Transformation needed")}

Error in accuracy(etsfit)$MAPE : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

> if(accuracy(etsfit)["MAPE"]<10){
+ fcast <- forecast(etsfit)
+ plot(fcast)}else{print("Transformation needed")}

Error in if (accuracy(etsfit)["MAPE"] < 10) {:missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: You need to use `p.value` instead of `pvalue`, according to [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseries/tseries.pdf).

Comment: Hey, thanks! This is shorter...

Comment: Hey, in continuation to the above question, I also want to extract the value of MAPE from the accuracy check. But I am getting an error. Could you help? Following is the code:

Answer (score 0):

figured out the answer. Thought it would be useful.

```
names(adf.test(Timeseries_1)) #to extract the pvalue of this test
if(adf.test(Timeseries_1)$p.value < 0.05){print("Time series is stationary")}
```